# Accelerate floatanimation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, sprite, firemonkey

there is a way to accelerate a floatAnimator in delphi ? such as increase or decrease velocity of a sprite when a key is pressed ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `duration` property to change the speed. for example changing Duration from 1 to 0.5 will double the speed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did it, but when the user presses the key at the beginning of the animation it works fine, but if it presses at the end it speeds up too much

Comment: it is because when you change the duration, the animation calculate current frame from **current_time/duration** and the new generated frame position is changed so much. you could use `Floatanimation.start;` after setting the duration to start it from beginning or set the duration in new variable and set it in OnProcess event when the currentTime=0